# Identifying the list of test cases failed in testng

Tags: testng

Could you please tell me how I can identify the list of test cases failed in suite execution using testng. I need to rerun the failed test cases Automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As part of the execution, testng generates a file called `testng-failed.xml` which contains all the details of methods that failed. If you are just looking for re-running failed tests, you can find this file (In a maven project it resides under the `target` folder.

You can do the following (I am going to assume that you are using maven):

1. Accept the suite name in your surefire plugin via a Maven property.
2. Modify the surefire plugin to refer to the maven property for the suite name.
3. Create a shell script or a batch file which does the following:

   1. Checks if the file `testng-failed.xml` exists in the target folder.
   2. If found then a rerun can be done.
   3. Take back-up of the surefire reports folder to some other place, this is because if its not done then the old reports gets overwritten.
   4. Re-run the tests by passing the `testng-failed.xml` location to the Maven property that is being used in your surefire plugin.

That should do.

The other option is to basically build an implementation of `org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer` and bind that with your `@Test` method. This will cause TestNG to try invoking the `@Test` method once again if it fails, till the `IRetryAnalyzer` implementation returns back a `false` indicating TestNG not to try any more.

Here's a sample

```java
public class MyRetry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

  private int retryCount=0;
  private int maxRetryCount=1;

  @Override
  public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
      retryCount++;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
public class GitHub1241Sample {

  @Test(retryAnalyzer = MyRetry.class)
  public void test2() {
    Assert.fail();
  }
}
```

If you use a retry analyzer, you dont need to take backup of the reports etc.,

Comment: @VigneshV.A - If my answer helped, please accept it.